# Selecting even rows through it class name

Tags: jquery

Problem selecting even rows through it class name:

```
$(".recDetails table tr").each(function() {
        if( !($(this).css("display") == "none")){
            $(this).addClass("block");
        };

    });

$(".recDetails table").each(function(i) {
         $(this).find("tr.block:even").css("background-color", "#fff");
         $(this).find("tr.block:odd").css("background-color", "#efefef");
    });
```

It is taking into the count all of the "**tr**" so:

```
(1) tr class="block"
(2) tr 
(3) tr class="block"
```

Comment: So you want to select just the even/odd tr's that have class block? Instead of even/odd of all tr's?

Comment: Your code is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/jR75X/

Comment: Yes exactly: Fiest: I found all the "tr" that have display block and then i wnat to count them and add a class if they areeven or odd

Comment: That should work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/MvEMW/1/

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem the thing is i have sub tables into the "tr" im not showing so is counting them as well so probably i have to count them separetly. First the one in the first level and then the one in the second level any idea on this? to do it with less lines as posible

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one;

```
.block:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
.block:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: But I need fallback support

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem the thing is i have sub tables into the "tr" im not showing so is counting them as well so probably i have to count them separetly. First the one in the first level and then the one in the second level any idea on this? to do it with less lines as posible

Comment: $(".recDetails > table").each(function(i) { }); this will get only the parent table tr's i guess

Comment: ok and then i have to do the same for the sub tables right (the tables insede tables) but what if i want to do this dinamic like If i dont know how many level im gonna have .eg table > table > table

Comment: You want to do it for all at once or one by one?

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery i do the following

```
$(".recDetails > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

then

```
$(".recDetails > tbody > tr:not(.odd)").addClass("even");
```